# Why does the selected segment color become clear in a UISegmentedControl when rotating the screen (Xcode 11 beta5)?

Tags: uisegmentedcontrol, ios13, xcode11

For example anchor a UISegmentedControl to the side margins and vertically centre in the view controller and then rotate the emulator.

The same segment is still selected and the font is bold. Just the selected segment color is no longer displayed.

You can see the other segments toggle to bold when selected but still without the selectedSegmentTintColor color.

Inspecting the view hierarchy shows that the UIImageView representing the selected color becomes clear. Trying to set selectedSegmentTintColor to restore the color after rotation does not seem to work reliably - i.e. it works once.

Rotating back and forth does seem in some cases to restore the selected color.

Comment: If you found a bug in iOS 13, submit a bug report to Apple with a simple app that fully replicates the issue. Time is running out to get such bugs fixed before iOS 13 comes out.

Comment: OK - so I have sent feedback (FB7023755) to Apple with a simple Xcode project.

Comment: It seems that the bug is now only present in the simulators after the release of the latest iOS 13 beta 7 for devices. I suspect the Xcode (still beta 5 at the time of writing) simulators are lagging behind in their UI code. I shall mark this question answered if Xcode 11 beta 6 provides simulators that solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed in iOS 13 beta 7 and then subsequently in the simulators when Xcode 11 beta 6 was released.